# How to write condition to pretend go over array size?

Tags: java, arrays, size

Iam doing homework and i have problem with two dimensional array. To be specific i have to find highest sum of numbers and write left hand corner and right corner. But how to write condintion when the number is in the corner ? 
There is an image https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEBkn.jpg

I already tried to start FOR from 1 not from 0 and it works but i want more effective way

```
int[][] pole = new int[6][6];
Random sc1 = new Random();
int a = 0;
for (int j = 1; j < pole.length - 1; j++) {
    for (int i = 1; i < pole.length - 1; i++) {
        a = sc1.nextInt(9) + 1;
        pole[i][j] = a;
    }
    if (j == 4) {
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < pole.length; j1++) {
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < pole.length; i1++) {
                System.out.print(pole[i1][j1] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This one works but i had to used this wrong way...

Comment: Start simpliflying you the problem by writing two private functions : one that returns you the sum of values in a line from column a to column b, and another returning you the sum of values in a column from line a to line b.

Comment: Ok i will try thank you (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞